# Regular expressions with java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string as below.

```
    $Alarm:com.Alarm(a  ==  123 || (count  ==  12345 || (time  matches  "24" && pqr =="1"))) 
$Event:com.Event(b  ==  123 || (co  ==  12345 || (time  matches  "204" && pqr =="22")))
```

whenever i encounter the above string i need to generate the following string.I mean i need to append the string `"from AlarmStream"` for the substring `$Alarm:com.Alarm(...)` and `"from EventStream"` for the substring `$Event:com.Event(...)`  as below.

```
    $Alarm:com.Alarm(a  ==  123 || (count  ==  12345 || (time  matches  "24" && pqr =="1") )) from AlarmStream

$Event:com.Event(b  ==  123 || (co  ==  12345 || (time  matches  "204" && pqr =="22"))) from EventStream
```

I am currently using the following pattern to acheive the same in java.

```
 Pattern alarmPattern = Pattern.compile(".*?\\.Alarm\\(([^\\(]*?|\\([^\\)]*?\\))*\\)");
 Pattern eventPattern = Pattern.compile(".*?\\.Event\\(([^\\(]*?|\\([^\\)]*?\\))*\\)");
```

But i am not getting the correct output.

Please provide me some pointers to achieve the correct output.The regular expression should consider only the last parenthesis and here the number of left and right parenthesis pairs are not fixed.It may increase or decrease.So the logic should work for any number of left and right parenthesis pairs.

Comment: Are you saving an Alarm and an Event objects to file? See java.util.Properties (for human-readable text properties) and java.io.Serializable. There's also JAXB for XML serialization.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need RegEx here. I think even this type fo code should work fine for you:

```
if (str.startsWith("$Alarm:com.Alarm"))
    str = str + " from AlarmStream";
else if (str.startsWith("$Event:com.Event"))
    str = str + " from EventStream";
```

Comment: Here the problem is the string does contain not only these two strings( $Alarm:com.Alarm(a  ==  123 || (count  ==  12345 || (time  matches  "24" && pqr =="1") )) from AlarmStream.these two strings are substrings of the actual incoming string.but the exact position is not known.

$Event:com.Event(b  ==  123 || (co  ==  12345 || (time  matches  "204" && pqr =="22"))) from EventStream)

Comment: In that case you can use [String#contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) instead of `startsWith`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to previous solutions:

```
str += str.startsWith("$Alarm:com.Alarm")?" from AlarmStream":str.startsWith("$Event:com.Event")?" from EventStream":"";
```

Comment: it does not work the reason being -->Here the problem is the string does contain not only these two strings( $Alarm:com.Alarm(a == 123 || (count == 12345 || (time matches "24" && pqr =="1") )) from AlarmStream.these two strings are substrings of the actual incoming string.but the exact position is not known. $Event:com.Event(b == 123 || (co == 12345 || (time matches "204" && pqr =="22"))) from EventStream)